# How to set a different color for ListViewItem based on value?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to set a different color based on the item value of a ListView, what I did so far:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Collections}">
   <ListView.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource SignColorConverter}}" />
       </Style>
   </ListView.Resources>
   <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                 <GridViewColumn Header="Item1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item1}"/>
                 <GridViewColumn Header="Item2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item2}"/>
```

the converter:

```
public class SignColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var input = System.Convert.ToInt32(value as string);

        //this method simply check if the value is between a range.
        if (GeneralUtility.IsInRange(input, 0, 20))
        {
            return Brushes.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

the problem's that the `input` value in the converter is even `0`. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE**

The `Collection` property contains these values:

```
public List<Collection> Collection  
{
     public Item1 { get; set; }
     public Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

so essentially I need to pass in the style:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource SignColorConverter}}" />
       </Style>
```

each `Item` value of `Collection`, and evaluate the value on the converter.

Comment: Based on what value are you trying to set the backgroundcolor? Is it Item1?

Comment: I don't have time to test it, but it looks like you are binding the style to the ListViewItem instead of to the DisplayMember. Not much information, but I hope this helps.

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian the value of `Item1`, `Item2` ...

Comment: Can you share more code on our viewmodel side

Comment: @zambonee is right, you are binding to the `ListBoxItem`, casting it to `string`, which is null, and converting this to an `int`, which results in 0.

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian added an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XAML binds the `ListViewItem` to the setter. When your `IValueConverter` converts the `ListViewItem` type, it returns 0 (if you used `int.TryParse()`, it would return `false`). What you are missing is that you have to bind the setter to a property in the `ListViewItem`. For example, if your `ListViewItem` is:

```
class item
{
    public object Item1 {get;set;}
    public object Item2 {get;set;}
    public int Color {get;set;}
}
```

Then your XAML can be:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Collections}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:SignColorConverter x:Key="SignColorConverter"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource SignColorConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Item1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item1}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Item2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item2}"/>
...
```

Or if you have to evaluate multiple item properties, your XAML can stay the same as OP:

```
...
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}, Converter={StaticResource SignColorConverter}}"/>
    </Style>
...
```

And then you have to evaluate the `ListViewItem` as the appropriate type in the `IValueConverter`:

```
public class SignColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var input = (item)value;
        if (input != null)
        {
            int item1 = int.Parse(input.Item1);
            int item2 = int.Parse(input.Item2);
            //Your logic here
            return Brushes.Red;
        }            
        else
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, but if I need to evaluate the value of each item? So instead of `Color` in the value,  what I need to add? Thanks.